# Refactor three state button

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

I have a button (or icon) which can have three states.

On hover, it changes state and on click, the new state gets transferred to another state. This state is kept until you click again for which it gets back to normal.

The code is working, but it does not look or feel good. Is there any way I can re-factor this?

- [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6qwt2vf8/)
- [More real example](http://jsfiddle.net/6qwt2vf8/1/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="rendering-expert request-list-supported">
    <i class="fa fa-cog">1</i>
    <a class="hidden" rel="request-list-add" href="/add/1">
        <i class="icon fa fa-plus-circle">2</i>
    </a>
    <a class="hidden" rel="request-list-remove" href="/remove/1">
        <i class="icon fa fa-check-circle">3</i>
    </a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.hidden { display: none; }
```

**JQuery**

```
$(function() { 
    $(".rendering-expert.request-list-supported").hover(function() {
        if (!$(this).hasClass("has-request")) {
            $(this).find(".fa-cog").hide();
            $(this).find("[rel='request-list-add']").removeClass("hidden");
        }
    }, function() {
        if (!$(this).hasClass("has-request")) {
            $(this).find(".fa-cog").show();
            $(this).find("[rel='request-list-add']").addClass("hidden");
        }
    }).on("click", "[rel='request-list-add']", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var toggler = $(this);
        var href = toggler.attr("href");
        toggler.parent().find(".fa-cog").hide();
        toggler.next("[rel='request-list-remove']").removeClass("hidden");
        toggler.toggleClass("hidden");
        toggler.parent().toggleClass("has-request");
    }).on("click", "[rel='request-list-remove']", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var toggler = $(this);
        var href = toggler.attr("href");
         toggler.parent().find(".fa-cog").show();
         toggler.prev("[rel='request-list-remove']").addClass("hidden");
         toggler.addClass("hidden");
         toggler.parent().removeClass("has-request");
    });
});
```

Please note that some parts are stripped in this example. It will only change state in my production if an AJAX request succeeds.

Comment: Is there a semantic rationale for writing the HTML that way (`<div>` with three children)? Would it also be acceptable to just have one element whose `class` changes for each state?

Comment: The div has a lot of other properties. Just stripped a lot for this example

Comment: May I suggest that you post the real thing, or something very close to it? There's no sense seeking advice that [won't be useful to you](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1709/9357).

Comment: Hi again, see: http://jsfiddle.net/6qwt2vf8/1/

Comment: There should be a functionaæ

Comment: Functional demo - hover the icon

Comment: Why you use the gear icon? It's totally useless and let people think that they can use it to change something

Comment: Its a demo, i use a custom icon set which i can not include on jafiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since jquery event handler is a memory and processing "eater" because has to listen for the events then I think is better to delegate the hover responsibility to css. The change is just remove `class="hidden"` from your elements and then set the right selectors to user `display:none` to hide or `display:inline` to show - I use `inline` instead of `block` since it is applied to anchor tag and the default behavior for this tag is `inline`.

With this change then javascript can be simplified and the hover handlers can be removed.

BTW you still have to implement the click handler to add the `has-request` class.

The code should look likes the following,

In your css:

```
.rendering.rendering-expert.request-list-supported:hover [rel=request-list-add],
.rendering.rendering-expert.request-list-supported.has-request [rel=request-list-remove] 
{
    display: inline
}
.rendering.rendering-expert.request-list-supported [rel=request-list-add],
.rendering.rendering-expert.request-list-supported [rel=request-list-remove],
.rendering.rendering-expert.request-list-supported:hover .fa-cog,
.rendering.rendering-expert.request-list-supported.has-request .fa-cog,
.rendering.rendering-expert.request-list-supported.has-request [rel=request-list-add]
{
    display: none
}
```

And then replace your js:

```
$(function() { 
    $(".rendering-expert.request-list-supported").on("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var toggler = $(this);
        toggler.toggleClass("has-request");
    });
});
```